# Row number within an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, numbers, row, ssrs-grouping

I have a group in my report where I have to use row numbers within that group, I was wondering if there is a way to display row numbers using expressions, or if I have to modify my Store procedure and include row numbers for that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, row number is the answer.
use it like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, ... ORDER BY Col1) AS recID
```

Here is how to do Paging in SQL

```
DECLARE @startRow INT
SET @startrow = 50
;WITH cols
AS
(
    SELECT table_name, column_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns
)
SELECT table_name, column_name, totrows + seq -1 as TotRows
FROM cols
WHERE seq BETWEEN @startRow AND @startRow + 49
ORDERBY seq
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response.. i'll have to add this in my store procedure.. But the problem is I have multiple groups (Dynamic) within the report..

Comment: In that case, put the groups in the PARTION BY clause so it matches your report

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RowNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225.aspx) function in Reporting Services.

Since SQL Server 2005 this can be done with [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in the SQL code too.

Neither way is better for simple groups, but if you have dynamic groupings that you're better with the SSRS RowNumber which will calculate over the group/scope

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick response. could you also help me with the syntax.. I'm a newbie and i'm trying to learn..

Comment: I'm trying something like this in the expressions box:  = RowNumber("mileStone") where the milestone is the group within which I need the row numbers.. however in the preview it shows 8,4,4,32(Multiples of 4) adjacent the rows.. I'm confused